# Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function - Javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jslint

I'm following a tutorial on how to create dynamically updating comments within a form. The guide I'm following keeps presenting errors and the one I have just recently found is not letting me fix it. it's telling me that I need to move 'var' declarations to the top of the function. There is also no definition of '$'

Any help is appreciated!

Here's is my JavaSript

```js
var comment = [
    {"name": "name1", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here1"},
    {"name": "name2", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here2"},
    {"name": "name3", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here3"}
];

for (var i=0;i<comment.length;i++){
    var html = "<div class='commentBox'><div class='leftPanelImg'><img src='images/Reviews/Comment%20pic.jpg'></div><div class='rightPanel'><span>"+comment[i].name+"</span><div class='date'>"+comment[i].date+"</div><p>"+comment[i].body+"</p></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"
    $('#container').append(html);
}
```

Here's my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Reviews</title>
        <link href="css/Review.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
    
    
    <div class='form'>
        <h3>Please write a review about your stay</h3>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name"/> <br> <br>
    Date: <input type="date" id="date"/> <br> <br>
    Comment: <textarea rows="7" col="30" id="bodyText"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" id="addComment" value="Submit">  
    
    </div>

    <h2>Comments</h2>

    
    <div id='container'>
    
    
    </div>
    <a href="{{ url_for('Index.html', id='content') }}">Go to Homepage</a>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Review.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*i need to move 'var' declarations to the top of the function*". That is suspect advice. Variables declared with *var* are processed before execution begins, moving the the declaration makes no difference (however, initialisation might).

Answer (score 2):

The linter is telling you that you should declare `i` and `comment` at the same point that the *interpreter* sees the variable is declared, which will either be at the top of the innermost function, or if you're on the top level already, at the very top of the top level. For example, for your code:

```
var i;
var comment;
var html;
comment = [
    {"name": "name1", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here1"},
    {"name": "name2", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here2"},
    {"name": "name3", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here3"}
];

for (i=0;i<comment.length;i++){
    html = "<div class='commentBox'><div class='leftPanelImg'><img src='images/Reviews/Comment%20pic.jpg'></div><div class='rightPanel'><span>"+comment[i].name+"</span><div class='date'>"+comment[i].date+"</div><p>"+comment[i].body+"</p></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"
    $('#container').append(html);
}
```

If you don't do this, you can confuse yourself due to `var`'s unintuitive hoisting problems - that's what the linting rule is for. (It's not a Javascript interpreter error, it's only an error thrown by your linter.)

That said, you might consider using modern syntax instead, with `const` and `let`, which are *not* hoisted, and you can use array methods instead of `for` loops for more functional and terse code, if you wish:

```
const comment = [
  {"name": "name1", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here1"},
  {"name": "name2", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here2"},
  {"name": "name3", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here3"}
];
comment.forEach(({ name, date, body }) => {
  const html = "<div class='commentBox'><div class='leftPanelImg'><img src='images/Reviews/Comment%20pic.jpg'></div><div class='rightPanel'><span>"+name+"</span><div class='date'>"+.date+"</div><p>"+body+"</p></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"
  $('#container').append(html);
});
```

You also might consider using a modern linter, like ESLint. JSLint is quite old and does not understand much of the nice syntax sugar modern JS allows us.

Comment: I disagree, particularly in regard to for loops. It's extremely common to declare the variables in the loop, moving the declaration elsewhere means you have to go looking for it. And declaring *comment* immediately before initialising it makes no sense.

Comment: Based on your scenario, I'd avoid placing "i" at the top. It's only an iterator variable and it's best to keep it enclosed in the loop

Comment: Would it be potentially better for them to just use `let` ?

Comment: Nice, the edit definitely looks like the way I would go. It would avoid any strange hoisting bugs.

Comment: @RobG @roland Yes, it is extremely common, but the linter OP is using *requires* `var` variables to be declared at the same place they're hoisted to.

Comment: So it goes to personal preference. In this case, *const* can be replaced by *let* or *var*, it doesn't make any practical difference (though I'd likely not bother with *html*).

Comment: @RobG The issue with `var` is that using it with OP's linter would *require* that variables declared with it be declared at the top and alone, which, like you say, is uncommon (not to mention ugly, and silly-looking when you're just going to assign to one of them on the next line)

Comment: @Jacob— *var* is much more tolerant than *let* or *const*, so "strange hoisting bugs" aren't likely to be an issue. ;-) The author if JSLint just had some strong opinions on how to address perceived shortcomings of the language.

Comment: @RobG Well, I was considering let and const are lexical and var is hoisted "to the top" I was implying this wouldn't be an issue with the newer syntax. I am getting though this is not a technical issue as much as a semantic one.

Comment: @RobG, CertainPerformance cleared that up for me with their last comment as well. Thank you though for the follow up.

Comment: @Jacob—no problem. *let* and *const* are really just to help developers not make mistakes (but introduce other issues) and cross–compiling from other languages. I find declaring an object with *const* then modifying it to be non–semantic, but maybe that's just me. :-)

Comment: @RobG Thanks, I will keep that in mind I appreciate the nugget of wisdom.